# como retornar a quantidade de casas decimais depois da virgula em c ou javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como retornar a quantidade de casas decimais depois da vírgula em c ou javascript;

Exemplo:

Para a entrada

2.254

A saída seria

3

Comment: Queres saber a quantidade ou os numeros depois da virgula?

Comment: Coloque o seu número em uma varíavel, passe-o para string, diviga a string no ponto e então conte os caracteres: `var a = 1.2345; a.toString().split('.')[1].length`

Comment: O que você procura não é arredondamento?

Comment: Seria algo assim que procuras? https://jsfiddle.net/cpjw12ub/